# Unwanted CSS delay when setting transition duration

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I want the menu to close in the same duration it takes for it to open. For some reason, there is a delay before closing, along with showing some extra space I have no idea where it comes from.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m9pd8bjh/7/

Here's the CSS code in case you see something wrong immediately:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked~.toggleable {
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.toggleable {
  transition: visibility 5s ease-in-out, overflow 2.5s ease-in-out, max-height 2.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I'm using a checkbox-label combination to trigger the opening and closing of the menu.

Comment: "max-height 2.5s ease-in-out" - remove the 's' after 2.5 here

Comment: @Sampada does nothing for me. Makes the whole line invalid. What's the purpose of doing so?

Comment: that is reducing the extra space that you have at the end of first click of Menu . also, overflow is not a CSS animatable property. Ref this - http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is that the `visibility` property in CSS cannot be animated. This is due to it only having two states (either visible or hidden, nothing in between to facilitate the animation).

If you want to make a fade-in effect, you can use `opacity:0;` to `opacity:1;` and give that a transition instead.

The next thing to note is that your animation time is very long, and if you are animating a `max-width`, you need to shorten the animation  time to adjust.

See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/m9pd8bjh/12/

And CSS:

```
.toggleable {
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

If you specifically want that long animation timeframe, then you will have to use something other than a max-height solution.

This would then become a new avenue to approach as you would have to use JavaScript, jQuery or some other such framework.

For future reference, here is a fiddle doing the same using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/m9pd8bjh/15/

And here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.toggler').click(function(){
    $('.hide').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: I was using 5s for testing purposes (I'd set a small number so the users can enjoy the seamless animation without having to wait), so I would be able to see it happen slowly. Thank you for your explanation. So, I take it CSS properties with no numeric values cannot be transitioned?

Comment: Anytime :) Yes, that is a great rule of thumb to use. CSS transitions are only useful for things that can be numerically measured. I.E. a hex code color can be transtioned (from let's say #000000 to #8fbce3) because it can still be measure in a hexadecimal numerical system.

Comment: Actually, I realized why it was solved when you made the jsfiddle. The max-height was 1000, going very slow from 1000 to 0, while everything would quickly show when opening up since the elements show up at ~50px. When you set it to 100px, it opened up much faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I add another transition when you close the menu and I removed the initial margin of the `ul` element. Is that effect ok for you ?

> CSS code changed

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.5s ease-in-out, overflow 0.5s ease-in-out, max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#menu-main { margin: 0;   padding: 10px 40px }

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .toggleable {
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: visibility 2.5s ease-in-out, overflow 2.5s ease-in-out, max-height 2.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9pd8bjh/11/)

Comment: There's still a bit of delay when it closes.